# «Помнить о» или «помнить кого/что»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, падежи, глаголы, управление

Что употреблять после глагола «помнить»: существительное в винительном падеже или существительное с предлогом «о»?

Возможно, верны оба варианта. Нигде не могу найти ответ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Верны оба варианта.

> **ПОМНИТЬ,** -ню, -нишь; ***нсв.** кого-что, о ком-чём, про кого-что и с придат. дополнит.* Удерживать в памяти, не забывать. *П. своё детство. П. стихотворение наизусть. П. о своих обязанностях. П. о друзьях. Помни о дочери, береги её. Хорошо помню вас.*

Источник: Большой толковый словарь ([Грамота.ру](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x)).